# Is there a power problem with Dell Inc. OptiPlex 3040 using Mantic Minotaur

Tags: dell, shutdown, 23.10

This OptiPlex 3040 does not shut down right from 23.10 (seems to keep running since the power light stays on). But when it is forced to shut down (by holding the button) and then restarted it tries to start (lights and sounds) and then shuts down for real. Maybe it sometimes goes through that more than once. I tried both the installed 23.10 and the live stick and both had the problem. There is no problem with 23.04 or the ancient and disused Widows 10 partition.

Comment: Good job troubleshooting! Please file a bug report against the "linux" package for this issue.

Comment: Thank you. Your implication that the problem is with the new 6.5 kernel is correct. I started to use ubuntu-bug but could see no way to indicate the nature of the problem (and of course there is no crash report in this case). How do I make a meaningful bug report?